# Why does R claim my object is not logical?

Tags: r

I have a simple class question here, and I'm getting stumped.
In this one, where I'm only supposed to use `ifelse`. First few lines work fine, but the if the my `x` is logical, the function should turn any `TRUE` into the word "White", and any `FALSE` into the word "Black".

```
q5 <- function (x) {
  ifelse (is.numeric (x),
         (div_three <- which (x %% 3 == 0)) &
             (not_div_three <- which (x %% 3 != 0)) &
             (x [div_three] <- (x [div_three] / 3)) &
             (x [not_div_three] <- (x [not_div_three] * 2)),
          ifelse (is.character (x),
                  stop ("Input is a character."),
                  ifelse (is.logical (x),
                          (is_true <- which (x == "TRUE")) &
                          (is_false <- which (x == "FALSE")) &
                          (x [is_true] <- "WHITE") &
                          (x [is_false] <- "FALSE"))))
  x
}
```

However, whenever I run `q5 (c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))` for example, I get this error:

```
 Error in (is_true <- which(x == "TRUE")) & (is_false <- which(x == "FALSE")) &  : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

This vector is definitely logical. I tried turning it into character before inserting the words, and also tried using a new element but it's all the same.
Id love some help figuring out what this message means, given that my element is, in fact, logical.
Thank you!

Comment: `(x [is_true] <- "WHITE")` will return "white" and `(1 & "WHITE")` will throw that error, I would abandon ifelse right now, this is already hard to read and debug

Comment: Unfortunately this is supposed to be done using `ifelse`. Of course I could do it easily without it, but...

Comment: `q5 <- Vectorize(function(x) ifelse(is.numeric(x), ifelse(x %% 3 == 0, x * 2, x / 3), ifelse(is.character(x), stop('chr'), ifelse(is.logical(x), ifelse(x, 'WHITE', 'BLACK'), NA)))); q5 (c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace your code for is.logical(x) with this. error was because in the evaluation "WHITE" & "FALSE" was occuring, because in R, anything inside () gets returned. You can try running x <- "R" and (x<-"R") to see the difference

```
ifelse (is.logical (x), x <- ifelse(x, "WHITE", "FALSE"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That solved it. They made us use `ifelse` so much, I forgot about the most simple solutions with it.

Comment: The outer `ifelse` should be an `if`. Don't use `<-` inside `ifelse`.